Formulate a weak form of a PDE
I am struggling in learning how to obtain a weak form for a PDE.

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$   be a bounded and smooth domain. We
consider the boundary value problem: \begin{equation} \begin{split}
>     -\text{div}(A\nabla u)+\alpha u = 0  \ \ \ in \ \Omega \  (1) \\
>     -\alpha\nabla u\cdot n=\beta(u-1) \ \ \ \ on \ \ \delta\Omega \ \ (2) \end{split}     \end{equation} where $A \in C(\Omega)$ is scalar
and positive, $\alpha, \beta > 0$ and where $n$ is the normal vector
of $\Omega$ pointing outwards

My attempt:

Formulate a weak form corresponding to this boundary value problem.

In order to formulate a weak form, let us multiply by a test function $v$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    (-\text{div}(A\nabla u)+\alpha u )v= 0  \ \ \ in \ \Omega \  (1)
\end{split}    
\end{equation}
Then we integrate
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
   \int_\Omega (-\text{div}(A\nabla u)+\alpha u )v= 0  \ \ \ in \ \Omega \  (1) 
\end{split}    
\end{equation}
and use integration by parts and the divergence theorem
\begin{equation}
    \int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} \, d\Omega = \int_{\partial \Omega} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS.
\end{equation}
But it is a little bit unclear how integration by parts is used here. Can anyone show my step by step?
Thanks

You want to use the following fact: If you have a vector field $\mathbf F$ and a function $v$, then
$$\mathrm{div}(v \mathbf F) = \nabla v \cdot \mathbf F + v \mathrm{div}(F).$$
Now if we take $\mathbf F= A \nabla u$ and $v$ your test function from above, then the divergence theorem tells us
$$\int_{\partial \Omega} (vA \nabla u )\cdot \mathbf n dS = \int_\Omega \mathrm{div}(A \nabla u) v dx + \int_\Omega A\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx.$$
Since $v$ is a test function, it vanishes on the boundary, making the left hand side of the last equality zero. Hence, taking the first term of the right hand side to the other side we obtain:
$$\int_\Omega -\mathrm{div}(A \nabla u) v dx = \int_\Omega A\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx.$$
This is exactly what you use for the weak formulation. We don't do anything with the term involving no derivatives and thus obtain as a weak formulation
$$\int_\Omega (A \nabla u) \cdot \nabla v + \alpha uv \ dx =0 \quad \text{ in } \Omega.$$
We have now got a formulation where only first derivatives appear (as opposed to second derivatives in the original formulation) and they only appear in an integral and hence only need to be integrable (not necessarily continuous as for classical derivatives), if e.g. $A$ has reasonable properties, it suffices to have $\nabla u \in L^2(\Omega)$.

Thanks for your answer! However, why did you add $\mathbf{n}$ to
$$\int_{\partial \Omega} (vA \nabla u )\cdot \mathbf n dS = \int_\Omega \mathrm{div}(A \nabla u) v dx + \int_\Omega A\nabla u \cdot \nabla v dx.$$ ? Can you show your steps in how you got that answer? I struggle to see the connection between your initial equation and the answer.

The $\mathbf n$ I added is from the divergence theorem (as you wrote it in your question): The integral of the divergence equals the integral of the inner product of the function with the outer normal on the boundary.
The very first equation of my answer shows how to calculate the divergence of $v A\nabla u$ which is why the right hand side of the second eqaution has this form
